# How to change the volume of the music? discord js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am working on a music command. How do I make it so the user who is using my bot can customize the volume. Like !volume 3 then the music volume will go down. Please help. My default volume is 5

My code:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}plays`)) {
        message.channel.send('Searching for your song...')
        execute(message, serverQueue).catch((_err) => {
            message.channel.send('I was not able to fulfill your request')
        })
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}skips`)) {
        skip(message, serverQueue);
        return;
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}stops`)) {
        if(!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('There is nothing playing')
        stop(message, serverQueue)
        return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you store the `VoiceConnection` in `serverQueue`?
If you did, you can get the `VoiceConnection` from your `serverQueue`, and get the `StreamDispatcher` with `VoiceConnection.dispatcher`. Then use the method `StreamDispatcher#setVolume` to change the volume of the music.